# Settings in the app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

As a suggestion, it would be nice if the users of the SE app, could choose the main page in the settings of the app to appear when they open the app. To illustrate, instead of having the “Feed” page as the first appeared page when they open the app, based on their own preferences they can see one of the sites’ home page, for instance “Computational Science” as their first appearance of the app.

Comment: App development is currently frozen, so it might take forever to have new features, if at all.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for your comment, you are right, I didn’t check the questions in the site, I just used “about:feature-request” to generate my question.

Comment: Sure, no problem :)